# Insertar elemento en array con búsqueda dicotómica

Tags: java

Buenas, necesito realizar una búsqueda en un array de enteros de forma dicotómica. Tras esto debo insertar un elemento pasado por parámetro en el array. Hasta el momento tengo el siguiente código desarrollado pero no se como insertar el elemento por parámetro. Gracias de antemano.

```
public boolean insertar (int elemento) { 

    boolean result = false;

    int inicio = 0;
    int fin = elementos.length - 1;
    int pos;

    if(elementos.length == size){
        result = false;
    }


    while (inicio <= fin) {
        pos = (elementos.length - 1) / 2;
        if (elementos[pos]  == elemento) {
            result = false;
        } else if ( elementos[pos] > elemento ) {
            fin = pos - 1;

        } else {
            inicio = pos + 1;
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: Dónde están definidos size y elementos?

Comment: En la clase principal como variables globales, size será el tamaño del array que se definirá posteriormente y elementos es el array de tipo int.

Comment: el `pos` en el while esta mal inicializado debe ser `pos = fin/2`. Otra cosa, si requieres insertar un elemento en un array de tamaño fijo y suponiento que este array ya está lleno, tendras que perder uno de los elementos para poder insertar uno nuevo, y esto lo puede hacer con un simple for. La solucion para que esto no pase, puede ser utilizando Listas o creando otro array de tamaño mas grande.

Answer (score 0):

Pues hasta donde tengo entendido un array no puede modificar su tamaño a menos que los instancies de nuevo.
la unica solucion que se ve en el horizonte es que crees un List:

```
     `List <String> miListaDePalabras = new ArrayList <String> ();
    String [ ] miArrayDePalabras = {"Oso", "León", "Buey", "Guepardo"};
    System.out.println ("Contenido inicial del ArrayList: " + miListaDePalabras);
    miListaDePalabras = Arrays.asList (miArrayDePalabras);`
```

agregues lo que necesites:

`miListadePalabras.add("Toro");
 miListadePalabras.add("Ganso");`

 y crees nuevamente un array apartir del List:

`int[] miArrayDePalabras = new int[miListaDePalabras.size()];
miArrayDePalabras = miListaDePalabras.toArray(miArrayDePalabras);`

Nota: Debes tener en cuenta que en los tamaños del array que sean impares habra hay que hacer algo adicional para tener control sobre eso.

Comment: Lo que me dices está muy bien y lo he hecho en otras ocasiones. El problema en concreto  esta vez es que soy yo el que tiene que desarrollar la estructura interna del contenedor. En esta ocasión se me pide lo siguiente : Desarrollo de un contenedor lineal en Java que use como estructura interna de representación un vector ordenado y realice las búsquedas de forma dicotómica. En concreto el método insertar.